# Remove range в EF Core и транзакция

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Когда мы производим удаление с помощью Remove range  в ef core у нас все выполняется в транзакции? Если, что то не удалится из списка удаляемых объектов откатится все?

Comment: Насколько я помню, любой вызов `SaveChanges` выполняется в транзакции. Но я не уверен.

Comment: спасибо, вы были правы)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Непосредственно удаление выполняется в транзакции, как и любой вызов `SaveChanges`/`SaveChangesAsync`.

Но надо понимать что без дополнительных телодвижений выборка данных из базы и их удаление - это две разные операции!

Если требуется чтобы выборка и удаление были в одной транзакции - транзакцию нужно создать явно:

```
using (var tran = ctx.Database.BeginTransaction()) 
{
    ctx.Foo.RemoveRange(ctx.Foo.Where(x => x.Bar = 42));
    ctx.SaveChanges();
    tran.Commit();
}
```

Comment: спасибо, за исчерпывающий ответ, я просто не знал, что SaveChanges делает все в транзакции)